# A different (less redundant) approach to Normalization

Tags: sql, database, database-normalization

Let's say we are to normalize a database into 3rd normal form using the requirement:

> I need a movie ticket registry program that can remember customers and
>   the tickets that they've purchased.

We might end up with a database like this:

```
ticket
    id
    movie_name
    price

customer
    id
    first_name
```

However, when I look at this, for some reason it looks redundant. What if I were to break it up into even smaller pieces, like this:

```
name
    id
    name

customer
    id
    fk_name_id

ticket
    id
    fk_name_id
    price
```

Would this be a good approach? Is there a name for this approach?

Comment: I think you'd call this over-normalization. A person's name and a movie's name are not the same sort of thing and there's not a good reason to use a single table to represent both. You're never going to have an instance where a person and a movie will share the same name and you'll want to use the same database entity for both.

Comment: Did Captain Philips or Erin Brockovich ever go to see the movies about themselves? :)

Comment: @Jordan: This approach wouldn't really be aiming at reusing data, it would be more focused on having minimal/flexible data structures for more accurate OOP resemblance

Comment: My name for it would be "a really bad idea".  :)

Comment: How would it be "more flexible"? It would be less flexible: it forces movie titles and customer names to use the same data type and size. If, say, we found that we needed to increase the length of our movie title field, we would be forced to also increase the length of the customer name field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jordan says, the point of breaking data out into a separate table is to avoid redundant data.

As you apparently realize, we do NOT want to lay out our tables like this:

```
WRONG!!!

ticket
  customer_name
  movie_name
```

That would mean that the customer_name is repeated for every movie he watches, and the movie name is repeated for every person who watches that movie. Lots and lots of redundant names. If the user has to type them in every time, it's likely that sometimes he mis-spells a name or uses a variation on a name, like we find our table includes "Star Wars", "Star Wars IV", "Star Wars Episode IV", and "Stra Wars", all for the same movie. All sorts of problems.

By breaking the customer and the movie out into separate tables, we eliminate all the redundancy. Great. Celebrate.

But if we take your suggestion of making a "name" table that holds both customer names and movie names, did we eliminate any redundancy?

If a customer has the same name as a movie -- if we happen to have a customer named "Anna Karenina" or "John Carter" or whatever (or maybe someone named their kid "Batman Returns" for that matter) -- are you going to use the same record to store both? If no, then you have not saved any redundancy. You have just forced us to do an extra join every time we read the tables.

If you do use the same record, it's even worse. What if you create a record for customer "Anna Karenina" and you share the id/name record with the movie. Then Anna gets married and now her name is "Anna Smith". If you update the name record, you have not only changed the name of the customer, but also the title of the movie! This would be a very bad thing.

You could, of course, say that if you change the name, that instead of updating in place you create a new record for the new name. But then that defeats half the purpose of breaking the names out to a separate table. Suppose when we originally created the movie record we mistyped the name as "Anna Karina". Now someone points out our mistake and we fix it. But with the "make a new record every time there's a change" logic, we'd have to fix each ticket sale one by one.

I guess you could ask the user if this is a change for just the movie title, just the customer name, or both. But now we've added another level of  complexity. And for what? Our program is more complex, our queries are more complex, and our user interface is more complex. In exchange, we get a tiny gain in saving disk space for the rare case where a customer coincidentally has the same name as a movie title.

Not worth it.

Comment: Great answer.  A more common variation on this I come across is "normalizing" addresses into a separate table, and then referencing the address table from multiple entities.  There are certainly cases where you have a legitimate reason to normalize an address, but in most cases it's 100% unnecessary.

Comment: @Jay: So how I intended for it to work is wherever there is a `name` column you'd reuse the same table instead of creating a `name` column in each table. CRUD operations work as usual and you wouldn't actually reuse `name` fields anywhere else except where the foreign key is linked to. A `name` & `id` would make up an entity where the `id` is a foreign key to an outside entity

Comment: @PhilSandler Okay, I'll give you that one: I have at times created a "person" table with name, address, city, state, postal code, phone number, email, etc. Then I use the same "person" table for employees, customers, etc. That seems to me to have some value: It's not really normalization but pseudo creating a data structure that can be invoked in multiple places. Sort of OOPy.

Comment: @ThreaT So if you never re-use the name records, what have you gained? You just have to do an extra join all the time. The db is more complex, queries are more complex and take longer, you use more disk space, and ... for what? There are a bunch of costs and I don't see any advantage?

Comment: @Jay: I guess it's cool if you're using a NoSQL database because then you don't actually need to do the old fashioned SQL-type queries. i.e. `Object DB`

Comment: @Jay: I don't think it's *bad* per se, just unnecessary.  Here is a very smart explanation of why: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22153914/151084 :)

Comment: RE not intending to re-use the name records: Well, okay, so you avoid the problems it would create. But then what's the gain? Instead of storing the name directly in, say, the Movie table, you store a pointer that links to another table, so if you want the actual name you have to do a join. What did you gain?

Comment: @PhilSandler If I click on that link, it just takes me right back here. I tried pasting it into the url box and it still takes me right back here. Hmm.

Comment: @Jay: yes, sorry, I meant it as a joke and a compliment.  I linked a smart explanation--*your* explanation.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Your first approach is not correct.  If you think about the problem, there are three entities:

- Movie
- Customer
- Ticket

The connection between `Movie` and `Customer` is really the `Ticket` table, so this is an example of an association or junction table that has additional information.

I wouldn't think of the problem as "there is an entity 'name' and customers and movies both have names".  The name is an attribute of other entities, it is not its own entity (at least in this case).

Comment: Thanks for your input but that's not really the point of my question... (don't mean to be harsh)

Answer (score 1):

Jay's answer is excellent, and should be chosen as the correct one IMHO.

However I wanted to add: normalization does *not* mean "storing like data in a separate structure".  That is absolutely not the intent of normalization, and this is a mistake made by a lot of inexperienced database modelers, especially when they have a programming (OOP) background.

Comment: Are you in touch with the NoSQL movement? I think data structuring and normalization is going to be a topic of discussion going forward considering providers like `Object DB` don't actually require SQL structures as it's an Object-Oriented database.

Comment: Agree. The point of normalization is to eliminate redundant data: every fact is only stored once. Well there may be times when we want to create a separate table to simulate a user-defined data type -- like the address example you mentioned in your comment on my post -- that has nothing to do with normalization. The reasons for doing it are totally different from the reasons for normalizing.